# Flutter JSON Foreach Text in Cateogories

Tags: json, flutter

I don't know how to apply foreach loop on json array.

Here is my example:

```
[{
"categories": [
        "categorie 1",
        "categorie 2",
        "categorie 3",
        "categorie 4"
    ]
}]
```

In Flutter I basicly have this:

```
Text(newData[index]['categories'], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600))
```

How to apply foreach loop on this json array to get `"Category 1"` in Text widget?

Comment: Is this what you want `newData[index]['categories'].map((value) => Text(value, ...)).toList();`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code and check if it works for you.

```
Colmun(children: newData[index]['categories'].map((value) => Text(value)).toList()),
```